# Using force vs time / space efficiency

Tags: haskell, graph, profiling, lazy-evaluation

Hi I am generating a sparse DAG of 1000 X 1000 nodes each having ~4 edges (direction). Here is the relevant code : [Full Code with imports](https://github.com/ashishnegi/hsalgos/blob/master/src/LongestEdgePathInDAG.hs)
The problem i am solving has values between [0-1500]. I have hardcoded 1501 as upper value for now. I am trying to calculate longest path of edges in the DAG. However, these details are not direct part of my question :

My question is related to how to judge the usage of `force` or similar constructs while writing algos in haskell :

```
type OutGoingEdges = Map.Map NodeId [ NodeId ]
type NodesData = Map.Map NodeId Node
type NodeId = Int

data DAG = AdjList
           { outGoingEdges :: OutGoingEdges
           , nodesData :: NodesData
           } deriving (Eq, Show)

makeDAG :: DAGDataPath -> IO (DAG, SourceNodes)
makeDAG filepath = do
  listOfListOfInts <- makeInteger <$> readLines filepath
  let [width, height] = head listOfListOfInts
      numNodes = width * height
      rows = (replicate width 1501) : (drop 1 listOfListOfInts) ++ [(replicate width 1501)]
      heightsWithNodeIdsRows = force . fmap (\ (row, rowId) -> fmap (\ (height, colId) -> (height, rowId * width + colId)) $ zip row [1..]) $ zip rows [1..]
      emptyGraph = AdjList Map.empty $ Map.fromList (fmap (\(h, nid) -> (nid, Node h)) . concat . tail . init $ heightsWithNodeIdsRows)
      emptyNodesWithEdges = Set.empty
      threeRowsInOneGo = zip3 heightsWithNodeIdsRows (drop 1 heightsWithNodeIdsRows) (drop 2 heightsWithNodeIdsRows)
      (graph, nodesWithInEdges) = DL.foldl' makeGraph (emptyGraph, emptyNodesWithEdges) threeRowsInOneGo
      sourceNodes = Set.difference (Set.fromList . Map.keys . nodesData $ graph) nodesWithInEdges
  -- traceShow [take 10 . Map.keys . nodesData $ graph] (return (Set.toList sourceNodes))
  -- traceShow graph (return (Set.toList sourceNodes))
  -- traceShow sourceNodes (return (Set.toList sourceNodes))
  return (graph, force $ Set.toList sourceNodes)

  where
    makeGraph (graphTillNow, nodesWithInEdges) (prevRow, row, nextRow) =
      let updownEdges = zip3 prevRow row nextRow
          (graph', nodesInEdges') = addEdges (graphTillNow, nodesWithInEdges) updownEdges
          leftRightEdges = zip3 ((1501, 0) : row) (drop 1 row) (drop 2 row)
          (graph'', nodesInEdges'') = addEdges (graph', nodesInEdges') leftRightEdges
```

Next line is interesting... `graph''` is `DAG` and `nodesInEdges''` is a `Set NodeId`

```
      in (graph'', nodesInEdges'')


    addEdges (g, n) edges =
      DL.foldl' (\ (!g', !n') ((p, pId), (c, cId), (n, nId)) ->
                  let (g'', n'') = if c > p
                                   then (makeEdge cId pId g', Set.insert pId n')
                                   else (g', n')
                      (g''', n''') = if c > n
                                     then (makeEdge cId nId g'', Set.insert nId n'')
                                     else (g'', n'')
                  in (g''', n'''))
                (g, n)
                edges
```

While profiling i found that, if i use `(force graph'', force nodesInEdges'')` instead of `(graph'', nodesInEdges'')`, **my memory usage reduces from 3 GB to 600 MB. But running time of program increases from 37 secs to 69 secs.** These numbers are from `time` command and looking at activity monitor. I also checked with profiling and it was similar results.

I am compiling profile builds with :
`stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-fprof-auto -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp -rtsopts" --file-watch`

I have ghc-7.10.3 and stack 1.1.2.

I think that `force` goes over the data structure again and again.

Can `force` be told to not go over the graph if it already fully evaluated ?

Can i use some other strategy ?

Sample Input:

```
2 2                    -- width height
1 2
3 4
```

Output:

```
3
```

Output is length of longest path in the graph. [4 -> 2 -> 1] i.e. [(1,1),(0,1), (0,0)]. Just to remind, correctness of program is not the question;
space/time efficiency is. Thanks

Comment: A separate matter: `IntMap` tends to be much faster than `Map Int`, and `IntSet` much faster than `Set Int`.

Comment: Please include your imports, by the way.

Comment: Also, include sample input and an expected output. Why do you have a hard-coded constant 1501?

Comment: @dfeuer i have included the full code link.

Comment: @chepner i have included sample input/output. but this question is not about input/output as such.

Comment: You have a lot of code, some of which is redundant or just "more" than necessary. For example: calling `head` and `drop 1` on the same list, when you could simply pattern match: `([width, height] : data) = listofListOfInts`. Things like this call the efficiency of your overall code into question.

Comment: @chepner thanks for these tips.. i would try to write it in more idiomatic way and present new changes.

Comment: @chepner but also, that part of code is same in both situations.. the question is about `force` and its effects.. I have tried best to not call fns like `length` (0 calls for length) and always tried to gather data from bottom-up to not calculate things more than once.. But if there is some mistake/suggestions .. please do tell.

Comment: What is `makeEdge`? Honestly, the reason you're having trouble getting answers is probably that your code is a giant blob. If you break it up into multiple, meaningful, well-documented functions, and include them all, we will be much more willing and able to wade into it.